# Can't run npm start, several errors

Tags: node.js

I have just installed node js on my laptop to follow this guide: https://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/docs/

But I get many 143 vulnerabilities after installing, I have read online that this shouldn't worry me too much but wehn trying to run npm I don't achieve to make it work.

this is the complete log I get when I try to start npm from the Command Prompt:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\lucpol\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.10
3 info using node@v15.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle webdataconnector@2.0.0~prestart: webdataconnector@2.0.0
6 info lifecycle webdataconnector@2.0.0~start: webdataconnector@2.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle webdataconnector@2.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle webdataconnector@2.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\lucpol\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\lucpol\webdataconnector\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\lucpol\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\lucpol\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle webdataconnector@2.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\lucpol\webdataconnector
10 silly lifecycle webdataconnector@2.0.0~start: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'node node_modules/npm-run-all/bin/npm-run-all --parallel corsproxy http-server'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle webdataconnector@2.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle webdataconnector@2.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: webdataconnector@2.0.0 start: `node node_modules/npm-run-all/bin/npm-run-all --parallel corsproxy http-server`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lucpol\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lucpol\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1063:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:295:5)
14 verbose pkgid webdataconnector@2.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\lucpol\webdataconnector
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\lucpol\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v15.5.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.10
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error webdataconnector@2.0.0 start: `node node_modules/npm-run-all/bin/npm-run-all --parallel corsproxy http-server`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the webdataconnector@2.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Anyone knows what that means?